# files in /tmp/cache/ of a new rails application (258 directories, 1404 files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my first question here (sorry for the possible misplacing) : what are all the files in /tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache of a new rails application (256 directories, 1403 files, 28,2 MiB) ? Are they necessary or can I delete them all ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: You are safe to delete the /tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache.

Long answer: [Bootsnap](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap), as I'm sure you're aware, is a Ruby library that optimizes and caches expensive computations, meaning you can boot Ruby/Rails applications *faster*.

One of the strategies Bootsnap employs to speed up your application is known as **Compilation Caching**.

Ruby has to translate **ruby source** into **internal bytecode**, which the **VM then executes**. What Bootsnap does is cleverly cache a bunch of these translations in cache files that consist of headers and cache contents (these are the files stored under the directory in question). This is done so that when your application performs its various operations, it can simply to do a lookup on the already-translated bytecode cached by Bootsnap, instead of performing the relatively-expensive compilation step, thus making the code execute faster.

A readable implementation of this concept can be found [here](https://github.com/ko1/yomikomu)

As you might have guessed by now, deleting those files will simply mean your application runs a **little slower** locally, until the operations are subsequently cached once more.

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, there is currently **no automatic purging mechanism** for Bootsnap's cache. The library leaves cleaning up the cache up to the user (a la `assets:clean` or container pruning).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Totally helping answer. Thanks a lot for taking the time. :)

Comment: Fantastic answer. Well written with good uses of emphases and links.